# how to restore cloud site on rackspace from files container

Tags: backup, backup-restoration, rackspace, rackspace-cloud

I have backed up my cloud site using http://www.zipitbackup.com/. It creates a backup file in Cloud sites/Container . Now i need to restore my site using this backup file. 
I don't find documentation on how can i restore my site from the backup.

Please suggest a solution for this,or any alternative which perform code+db backup of my cloud site and able to restore later.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I am actually the developer of the Zipit Backup Utility. I just happened to find this.

For restoring your site it should be fairly easy. You should have two files in their respective containers.

1 for the database and 1 for the files.

You will need to extract the files archive locally. You will then have the timestamped folder and inside you will see the lib logs and web folder.

Inside the web folder you will see the content folder. That is the folder that contains your site files. You can then use FTP to login to your Cloud Site and navigate to the content folder of your site and copy the contents of your local content folder to it.

Now for the database, you will need to extract the archive file for the database locally. This will give you the sql file for your database. If you still have the database in Cloud Sites created you can login to phpMyAdmin from the Cloud Sites control panel and drop all the tables from the old database. Then you can use the Import option in phpMyAdmin to import the sql file.

One thing to keep in mind is that when you export an sql file you typically end up with some stuff at the top of the sql file for creating the database if it doesn't exist. This can cause issues when importing in Cloud Sites since it is not allowed to create databases from phpMyAdmin in Cloud Sites. To work around that you can simply edit the sql file prior to importing and remove those lines from the sql file.

While we do not support this type of thing officially. I would be happy to assist you with this. If you can give us a call at our support number that you can find in your Cloud Sites control panel and ask for Jereme Hancock I will do my best to help where I can.

Also, fyi, I just release a major update to Zipit that you might want to check out. :)

Comment: Thanks Jereme. your answer is correct if we use ftp upload option. but i was trying to find option where i can restore directly from zip file on server. thanks for input

Comment: Hi Dashrath, Ahh... Well I have considered adding a "restore" option to Zipit. There are some concerns with doing that as it would/could overwrite customer data. However, I am working to really make Zipit more robust so I may need to look into that option again.

Comment: Suspicious circle-promotion of Zipitbackup.

Comment: @DeerHunter , you may think so. But then why don't you suggest some alternative so that people like me can know about it ?